# Having trouble creating a bag of objects - Scrabble word search

Tags: java

I have to create a scrabble word search for my data structures class.  I haven't reached the actual search yet.  First, I need to create a bag of scrabble tiles.  However, I keep getting errors when trying to add ScrabbleTile objects to my bag.

I have four classes: ScrabbleTile, ScrabbleBag, ScrabbleHand, and WordFinder.

Here is ScrabbleTile:

```
public class ScrabbleTile {
private char letter;
private int points;

ScrabbleTile (char letter)
{
    this.letter = letter;

    switch (letter) 
    {
        case '_':
            points = 0;
        case 'e':
        case 'a':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'n':
        case 'r':
        case 't':
        case 'l':
        case 's':
        case 'u':
            points = 1; break;
        case 'd':
        case 'g':
            points = 2; break;
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
        case 'm':
        case 'p':
            points = 3; break;
        case 'f':
        case 'h':
        case 'v':
        case 'w':
        case 'y':
            points = 4; break;
        case 'k':
            points = 5; break;
        case 'j':
        case 'x':
            points = 8; break;
        case 'q':
        case 'z':
            points = 10; break;
        default: System.out.println("Incorrect character.  Please enter a lowercase letter, a-z.");
            break;
    }
}

public char getLetter()
{
    return letter;
}

public int getPoints()
{
    return points;
}
```

}

Here is my ScrabbleBag class:

```
import DSLib.*;

public class ScrabbleBag {
private BagADT<ScrabbleTile> letterBag;

ScrabbleBag()
{
    letterBag = new Bag<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {letterBag.add(ScrabbleTile('e'));}
}
```

}

In the ScrabbleBag constructor, I'm trying to add the correct number of each letter tile, starting with "e".  Netbeans had a few suggestions which I tried, but then it was telling me the line syntax was wrong, after creating a few more instance variables in the ScrabbleBag class.  How can I properly add ScrabbleTile objects to the bag?

My professor was very clear that we cannot use methods ahead of what we've gone over in class.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please **edit** the question to give us the exact text of the error message you are seeing. If there is a line number, put a comment in your code pointing out which line corresponds to the error.

Comment: Try adding new in front of ScrabbleTile('e'))

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed `new` when create `ScrabbleTitle` object

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
   letterBag.add(new ScrabbleTile('e'));
}
```

Comment: wow.  it was really that easy.  thank you so much.  i was using the new keyword previously and getting an error.  i must have had the syntax wrong.  thanks!

Answer (score -1):

To create a `ScrabbleTile` you need the `new` keyword:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    ScrabbleTile tile = new ScrabbleTile('e');
    letterBag.add(tile);
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? In the absence of an error message, it's a good guess.

Comment: @slim (not the downvoter) A guess is not an answer. This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @slim it completely ignores the question of OP of how to properly add ALL tiles to the bag object.

Comment: @m_callens The question doesn't say anything about "all" tiles. This is probably the answer to OP's immediate problem.

Comment: @Mistalis I'm not guessing, how would that code compile without the `new` keyword? He's having compilation errors

Comment: `" I'm trying to add the correct number of each letter tile"`

Comment: @m_callens That's not his problem. He's having errors on that line inside the for loop.

Comment: `"Starting with 'e'"` -- she has written failing code to add 12 'e' tiles. That is the immediate problem. Once she knows how to do that, the other tiles will not be a problem (or at least, they'll be a different problem).